# Json encode auto converts values from decimal to string in array

Tags: php, mysql, json, string, decimal

I want to convert a table into json format but the fields are converted into strings. The values are stored in the table with datatype decimal(5,0). Table type in InnoDB

The php I code used is

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "data";
$tablename = "data";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `" . $tablename . "`;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$json_array = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $json_array[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($json_array);
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

This is the code i tried, the output im expecting is

```
[
    {
        "X": 2,
        "Y": 4,
        "Z": 6,
        "RX": 8,
        "RY": 10,
        ...
```

But the output I get is

```
[
    {
        "X": "2",
        "Y": "4",
        "Z": "6",
        "RX": "8",
        ...
```

Comment: PHP will receive them as _string_ values, that is just how it works. The _point_ of the DECIMAL type is to have _precise_ values, that are not subject to the imprecision that float values inherently come with. So if PHP received them _as_ floats already, that would be counterproductive.

Comment: I think you can use a flag like `json_encode($json_array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);` to have it convert the values to numbers. But keep in mind that the conversion depends on the `serialize_precision` setting in your php.ini file. Like @CBroe says, floats are inherently imprecise.

Comment: Calling floats "imprecise" is correct but also a bit of an oversimplification. To better understand what is meant read: [Floating point numbers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) and [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Use PDO. It will return numeric values as numbers instead of strings in modern versions of PHP.